# Nesting NDSolve, Manipulate and Plot functions

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations that I'd like to solve for different values of a parameter. I am doing so, by

```
 Manipulate[
 NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == 
    c*(3 - 2)*(x[t])^2 y[t] - c*(y[t])^2 x[t] - 1*x[t] + 1*y[t], 
   D[y[t], t] == 
    c*(3 - 2)*(y[t]) x[t] - c*(x[t])^2 y[t] - 1*y[t] + 1*x[t], 
   x[0] == 0.2, y[0] == 0.8}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}], {c, 0, 10}]
```

I then want to plot parametric plots of functions x and y, and plot the functions x and y vs t. For now, I am copying the output and feeding it into the respective plotting functions,

```
ParametricPlot[{InterpolatingFunction[], InterpolatingFunction[]}, {t, 0, 100}]
Plot[{InterpolatingFunction[], InterpolatingFunction[]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

As a Mathematica novice, I was wondering if there is someway to nest these three operations, so that the output gives me the the interpolating functions, and the two plots, and then I can vary the parameter c.

Comment: See `ParametricNDSolve` command.

Comment: So, you change your `NDSolve` to `sol=ParametricNDSolve[...]`, then `Manipulate[
Plot[Evaluate[{x[c][t], y[c][t]} /.sol], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All], {c, 0, 10}]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   sol = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == c*(3 - 2)*(x[t])^2 y[t] - c*(y[t])^2 x[t] - 1*x[t] + 1*y[t], 
      D[y[t], t] == c*(3 - 2)*(y[t]) x[t] - c*(x[t])^2 y[t] - 1*y[t] + 1*x[t], 
      x[0] == 0.2, y[0] == 0.8}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}],
   ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}],
   Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 100}]
   }],
 {c, 0, 10}]
```

[image]